# Django: How do I upload an image to a folder named after the article slug

Tags: django, django-models

I defined two models `Article`, `Article_photos`. Photos present in each article is stored in the relevant `Article_photos` model. I intend to store multiple photos per article in this way.
I want each photo to be uploaded to a folder by *naming the folder in this manner*: **{slug}_images**.

This is `Article` model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Author')
    article_title = models.TextField()
    article_content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.article_title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And the `Article_photos` model to store one or more photos:

```
class Article_photo(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='{}_images'.format(article.slug))
```

Now, when i'm running `makemigrations`, it's returning this error: `AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'slug'`.

How do rename the folder in the pattern I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of a function here, for example:

```
def article_photo_location(self, filename):
    return '{}_images/{}'.format(self.article.slug, filename)

class Article_photo(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=article_photo_location)
```

Note that you should *not* call the function, you pass a *reference* of the function to the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `ArticlePhoto` instead of <s>`Article_photo`</s>.